# how to dowload libgl.so.1?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

So I am running 64-bit hardware with Ubuntu and I am trying to play Quake 3 but I can't install `Libgl1`.

```
 sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Reinstallation of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Have you seen [this question on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/767000/236209)?

Answer (score 3):

I was generating a `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL` error when attempting to install kivy on ubuntu mate in virtualbox. Using the workaround below, I was able to complete the installation successfully using the following instructions.

```
sudo apt install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

As you know, i386 means the package you are trying to install is for 32bit system.

As explained here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/522372/installing-32-bit-libraries-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts-64-bit
you can install 32bit libraries in 64bit system.

At this link we read https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/949606 :

> 64 bit dev packages contain a 64 bit version of the library file(s) that they provide for linking but not a 32 bit version of the library file(s). In previous versions of Ubuntu, however, it was possible to compile 32 bit applications using the 64 bit dev packages in by installing ia32-libs, which contained the required 32 bit library files.
>
> In the move to multiarch, 32 bit library files are being removed from ia32-libs. Multiarch (I assume) aims to keep the architectures separate, so the generally intended solution is to install the i386 version of the dev package when compiling 32 bit applications, ie side-by-side with the 64 bit dev package.
>
> However, some 64 bit development packages conflict with their 32 bit equivalent. This creates a regressive situation where it is impossible to install them side-by-side - you are forced to either install the 32 bit package, which breaks 64 bit compilations, or the 64 bit package, which breaks 32 bit compilations.
>
> An example is libglu1-mesa-dev, which conflicts with libglu1-mesa-dev:i386. The libglu1-mesa-dev file contains all the necessary development files for 32 bit *except* for the 32 bit library file. It does contain the 64 bit library file. Since the library file is part of the development files, libglu1-mesa-dev does not contain all the necessary development files for 32 bit, ie it does not contain all the necessary development files for multiarch. I think that it *should* contain all the necessary files for building multarch applications.
>
> **The two workarounds are**:
>
> 1. Manually re-install the required i386 dev packages before compiling 32 bit apps, and then manually re-install the required amd64 dev packages before compiling 64 bit apps. This is a real pain.
> 2. Install the i386 binary package (eg libglu1-mesa:i386) and the amd64 dev package (eg libglu1-mesa-dev), and manually create symlinks for the i386 libXYZ.so package (eg sudo ln -s /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so). This is a more permanent solution but is a real pain to set up, as you have to find each missing library manually, and some library files, like mesa/libGL.so.1, are in subfolders.

Answer (score 1):

As an extention to what @GabrieleMartini said (and I'm glossing over a lot of detail, don't crucify me):

Your error message says:

```
Reinstallation of libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

First we need to resolve the "cannot be downloaded issue".
Try `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` (to consider 32-bit packages, per the [debian guide](https://wiki.debian.org/Steam#Intel)),
then `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` again.

While the linked information is a bit dated now, [Ubuntu's packages site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so.1) shows that the intel 32-bit (i386) library for libGL.so.1 is in the `libgl1-mesa-glx` package.

On a 64-bit (x86_64) system, you're generally going to receive the `x86_64-linux-gnu` version of the libGL.so.1 binary. When your package manager is setup to also look for 32-bit (i386) packages,
`libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` will specify that you want the i386 (32-bit) versions of that package's binaries, and should fix the "missing libGL.so.1" issue.

Hope this helped you :)

The rest is supplementary information if you're curious ...

---

Basically all

- static libraries (bundled with application binaries)

and

- dynamic libaries (joined with the application at launch time)

go into some directory (or folder, if that's familiar) called `lib`

On Linux, a lot of these are in `/usr/lib`, that is to say, usEr installed libRARIES.

There is a good chance you already had the 64-bit (x86_64) version of the libGL.so.1 binary, located at

`/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`

and what was missing was the 32-bit analogue at

`/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1`

which should appear after running `sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` which contains the 32-bit version binary of libGL.so.1 (again, according to the somewhat dated [Ubuntu's packages site](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=xenial&arch=any&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=libGL.so.1))

Answer (score 0):

For me using Ubuntu, I used `apt search` to successfully locate a package:

```
libgl1/jammy 1.4.0-1 amd64
  Vendor neutral GL dispatch library -- legacy GL support
```

Then a `sudo apt install libgl1` solves everything.
The installed dynamic libs are:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1  <--- Get it now
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_indirect.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX_mesa.so.0.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLdispatch.so.0.0.0
```